# Simple Formula to workout intervals

Tags: elementary-number-theory, computational-mathematics

Say we have scale from $1$ to $12$
We pick two numbers on this scale and trying to figure the shortest distance.
Say $x_1 = 2, x_2 = 4$ and we need to figure out y which in this case would be $y = 2$

Here is some examples:

$x_1 = 2, x_2 = 11$, $Y$ would be equal $2$

$x_1 = 1, x_2 = 5$, $Y$ would be equal $4$

$x_1 = 2, x_2 = 10$, $Y$ would be equal $3$

What would be the formula/equation for this? It's like clock with $12$ hours and we need to find shortest distance between $2$ numbers

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, for $x_1 = 2$, $x_2 = 11$, I believe $Y$ should be 3.

What you are describing as cycling around a clock is called modular arithmetic. So using the values above, $(x_1 - x_2) \mod 12 = (2 - 11) \mod 12 = -9 \mod 12 = 3$.

I believe you can go from here to find a formula for Y.

Comment: wow thanks @Olivia, will double check this if it should be 2 or 3 but either way this looks promissing

Comment: If you think of it as a clock face, there are three hours between 11 and 2.